# Loop array in object Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

im having a big problem :(
Im building a booking app and im trying to loop Dates in one option and and Times in another. The times should have de same Id as de Date for the right times. Im getting the dates and times of an api and the data looks like this:

```
 "PossibleStartTimes": [{
    "Date": "2019-03-06T00:00:00+01:00",
    "Times": ["07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00"]
  }, {
    "Date": "2019-03-07T00:00:00+01:00",
    "Times": ["07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00"]
  }, {
    "Date": "2019-03-08T00:00:00+01:00",
    "Times": ["07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00"]
  }, {
    "Date": "2019-03-11T00:00:00+01:00",
    "Times": ["07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00"]
  }, {
    "Date": "2019-03-12T00:00:00+01:00",
    "Times": ["07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00"]
  },
```

Heres a snippet from my vue component:

```
    <b-select
      @input="onChange($event)"
      v-model="selectedDate"
      size="is-medium"
      expanded
    >
      <option disabled value>Välj Datum</option>
      <option
        v-for="(PossibleStartTime, index) in PossibleStartTimes"
        :key="PossibleStartTime.date"
        >{{ index }} {{ PossibleStartTime.Date }}</option
      >
    </b-select>
    <div class="times">
      <h2 class="title is-3">Välj tid</h2>
      <b-select size="is-medium" v-model="selectedTime" expanded>
        <option disabled value>Välj Tid</option>
        <option
          v-for="(PossibleStartTime, index) in PossibleStartTimes"
          :key="PossibleStartTime.time"
          >{{ index }} {{ PossibleStartTime.Times }}</option
        >
      </b-select>
```

My idea is that when a customer select the Date, then the times would loop based on the id of the Date in se second "b-select" :(

Im using Buefy, and the times should only show up based on what Date the customer selected.

Hope anyone understand what i mean :)

Comment: `b-select`? Do you use Buefy or Bootstrap?

Comment: Buefy in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach: https://jsfiddle.net/umjLv0zq/2/

I used a standard `select` instead of `b-select`, but it shouldn't matter in this case.

What I did:

1. I removed `@input="onChange($event)"` from your `select`. It shouldn't be necessary if it's linked to property via `v-model`.
2. I added `:value` bound to `PossibleStartTime.Date` in each option. If you don't specify this, your `v-model` will be linked to whatever is inside of `<option>here</option>` making your `selectedDate` change to `{{ index }} {{ PossibleStartTime.Date }}`. You shouldn't need the index there right?
3. I added a new `computed` property that finds an array of `Times` related to `selectedDate`. If a day is found, it returns it's `Times` or an empty array otherwise.
4. And lastly, the second `select` (or `b-select` in your case) has options based on the computed property.

Btw. your `:key` is bound to either `Date` or a time/hour in your `Times` array. Think whether they are really unique.

Comment: You made my Day! :)

Comment: I have one more small issue, when a route to the "calender-route" im fetching dates and times, then i get Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined",

Comment: maybe i should add default value for selected date exampel index[0] :S

Comment: That's a different issue and you should actually start a new topic for this, but in short you have to make sure your `PossibleStartTimes` is set to `[]` by default in your `data`. `find` is an array method, so you have to use it on an existing array. When you fetch your data, you should assign it to `PossibleStartTimes` and it will recompute.